# Use class reference for state in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'd like to store a reference to a class in state but an error occurs.

Specifically, the following:

```js
useState(SomeClass)
```

results in:

```
 Class constructor SomeClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

...

I can find another route for my specific need but I'd like to understand what the issue is here exactly.

--

FWIW here's a concrete situation where the above would be useful:

Consider a component that displays a list of `Super[]` but filtered by subclass. The component contains a set of radio buttons to set the filtering. e.g.

```js
const FilterableListView = (props:{items:SuperType[]})=>{

const [SelectedType,setType] = useState(DefaultType as SuperType)// where DefaultType extends SuperType

const itemsToDisplay = props.items.filter(item=>item instanceof SelectedType) 

// in radio button callback somewhere...
setType(SomeOtherSubType)

...

}
```

Here the state is the filtering criteria. No need for instances of any of the class references.

Again, I can skin this cat in many ways — I just would like to know why `useState(Class)` results an attempt to instantiate `Class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you cannot use a class as state is because `useState` allows for [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state).

> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:

```js
// lazy initial state example
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

One possible solution is to wrap your class in an object, like `{ maker: MyClass }`. Here is a minimal complete example. Click the <kbd>create</kbd> to create objects. Click <kbd>⚫️</kbd> or <kbd>⬛️</kbd> to change the type of object that is created.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor() { this.value = "⚫️" }
}

class Square {
  constructor() { this.value = "⬛️" }
}

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState({ maker: Circle })
  const [elements, setElements] = React.useState([])
  return <div>
    <button
      onClick={_ => setMode({ maker: Square })}
      disabled={mode.maker === Square}
      children="⬛️"
    />
    <button
      onClick={_ => setMode({ maker: Circle })}
      disabled={mode.maker === Circle}
      children="⚫️"
    />
    <button
      onClick={_ => setElements([...elements, new mode.maker()])}
      children="create"
    />
    {elements.map(e => <div className="element">{e.value}</div>)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
button[disabled] {
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `useState()` hook supports [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), which means that if it receives a function, it will call it on the first (and only) render. The returned value would be used as the initial state.

To circumvent that, pass a function that returns the class as the initial state:

```
const [SelectedType, setType] = useState(() => SomeClass)
```

As [noted by よつば](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189202/use-class-reference-for-state-in-usestate-hook#comment125837580_71189368), the same thing would happen when you'll use `setType` to replace the class, since the `setX` function also supports [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). To update the state call:

```
setType(() => AnotherClass)
```